# SCM Manager Error: Server sent unexpected return value

Tags: linux, svn, version-control, nginx

Use SCM Manager, when you try to rename or copy \ move SVN folder fails.
Server sent unexpected return value (501 Method COPY is not defined in RFC 2068 and is not supported by the Servlet API) in response to COPY request for

Access to the SCM Manager through a proxy nginx. I suspect this is the issue, but not sure, here are the logs of nginx:

```
192.168.0.3 - dmitryu [24/Jun/2014:15:02:44 +0400] "COPY /scm/svn/factor/!svn/bc/66294/Sbrf/sbrf/trunk/re-standardization HTTP/1.1" 501 0 "-" "SVN/1.6.15 (r1038135)/TortoiseSVN-1.6.12.20536 neon/0.29.5"
192.168.0.3 - dmitryu [24/Jun/2014:15:18:57 +0400] "COPY /scm/svn/factor/!svn/bc/66295/Sbrf/sbrf/trunk/re-standardization HTTP/1.1" 501 0 "-" "SVN/1.6.15 (r1038135)/TortoiseSVN-1.6.12.20536 neon/0.29.5"
192.168.0.3 - dmitryu [24/Jun/2014:15:34:34 +0400] "COPY /scm/svn/factor/!svn/bc/66296/Sbrf/sbrf/trunk/re-standardization HTTP/1.1" 501 0 "-" "SVN/1.6.15 (r1038135)/TortoiseSVN-1.6.12.20536 neon/0.29.5"
```

Comment: Proxy-in-the-middle is **always bad idea**. nginx is worse even more

Comment: SVN/1.6.15 (r1038135)/TortoiseSVN-1.6.12.20536 neon/0.29.5

Try newer client. SVN 1.6 is no longer supported.